# How to make a Polyline update when bound to collection in Avalonia

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am trying to link a `Polyline` to an `ObservableCollection` of `Point`s in an Avalonia MVVM application and I'm able to get it to display the initial collection of points just fine, but when the collection is updated, the Polyline does not show any changes.

First I tried using `ReactiveUI`'s RaisePropertyChanged function, which works fine when I have a textblock or other control that can display text, but it doesn't actually update the polyline. So next I tried the WPF method of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged like this:

```cs
public class PCollection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Point> Points { get; set; }

    public PCollection()
    {
        Points = new(Database.GetPoints());
    }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

(from [Polyline bound to ObservableList<Point> doesn't refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643054/polyline-bound-to-observablelistpoint-doesnt-refresh))
(`Database.GetPoints()` returns an `IEnumerable<Point>`)
and notifying of changes by calling the PCollection instance's NotifyPropertyChanged function, but again that does not affect the Polyline after the page loads initially.

Other results that I found involved accessing and updating the binding itself from within the code, which with MVVM is not possible.

I also came across [this](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/3623) very relevant issues thread for Avalonia, but I have no idea how to make use of the "easy fix" posted there or even if it's possible without editing Avalonia's own code.

**Relevant code snippets:**
Part of my view containing the polyline and a button that creates a random point within the canvas in `CanvasView.axaml`

```xml
<Grid>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Width="250"
          Height="250"
          Name="ArtCanvas">
    <Canvas.Background>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="beige"/>
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Polyline Name="jef"
              Points="{Binding Points}"
              Stroke="black"/>
    </Canvas>
  
  <Button Grid.Row="2"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Content="boop"
          Command="{Binding DrawLine}"/>
</Grid>
```

Part of the viewmodel in `CanvasViewModel.cs`

```cs
public class CanvasViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Point> Points { get; };
    
    public CanvasViewModel()
    {
        Points = new(Database.GetPoints());
    }

    public void DrawLine()
    {
        System.Random rand = new();
        Point p = new(rand.Next(101), rand.Next(101));
        Points.Add(p);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Points));
        
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p); // shows that the point is actually created and added to the collection
    }
}
```

(`Database.GetPoints()` returns an `IEnumerable<Point>`)